# Toggle Item in Array

Tags: actionscript-3

Preface: I'm not a programmer, I'm an artist and I'm pretty terrible at AS3 and use very basic methods to achieve what I want even if it takes me the entire week to figure it out and end up with 1000+ lines of redundant code.

Question: I have 10 buttons on the stage in an array. They each have an "in" and "out" animation. How do I easily click any button and have it play the "in" animation while playing the "out" animation of any other button that was previously clicked? What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you have your code for handling the button press, loop through the array of buttons and check their `_state` status (or whatever variable/property tells you if the button is "in" or "out").  If it finds one that is "in", call the function that makes it go "out".

Some pseudo code for you to consider:

```
function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++){
        if (buttonArray[i]._state == "in"){
            buttonArray[i]._state = "out";
            // play button "out" animation
        }
    e.target._state = "in";
    // play e.target "in" animation
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept but in practice I don't. The ._state is confusing me. How do you apply a variable to a button instance?

I have it set up for 2 different arrays: 1 to generate button names and the 2nd to hold button variables for tracking active/inactive states.

Comment: Add the code in which you create your buttons. (Or are they made in the IDE?)

Comment: If they are made in the IDE I think you can select the button and press F9 to open the actions panel and then add `var _state:String;` in each button instance. If you create them at runtime it is much easier. All you have to do is add that same line of code up above the constructor in the class .as file.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I can't wrap my head around this. I'll just stick to the way I know how to do it which works. Thank you.

Comment: You can post your own solution then :) it may help someone else. But honestly if you are writing 1000 lines of code, I suggest spending 1.5 hours learning how to make a class for your buttons. I can walk you through it, but there are also plenty of tutorials. Let me know.